# Access violation writing location with pointers

Tags: c++, class, access-violation

I'm creating a program that puts the first letter of a word to the back of the word so "Word" would become "ordW" and I have done that fine but when I decided to put the function into a class it doesn't work, I get *access violation writing location* I have no idea what is wrong with it at all, I'll show the class code and the original code:

Class code:

```
void Checking::test(char* first,char* buffer){
back = first;
if (first != buffer + strlen(buffer) - 1){
    ++back;
    temp = *first;
    *first = *back;
    *back = temp;

    ++first;
    test(first, buffer);
}
}
```

Note: The variable "back" and "temp" are declared in the class header like so:

```
Char* back = NULL;
Char temp = NULL;
```

The original code:

```
void test(char* first, char* buffer){
char* back = first;
if (first != buffer + strlen(buffer) - 1){
    ++back;
    char temp = *first;
    *first = *back;
    *back = temp;

    ++first;
    test(first, buffer);
}
}
```

I have no idea why I am getting the error when using the same function but within a class. If someone finds the error could they explain why I am getting the error and how to fix, thanks.

Comment: I would use the debugger in this case.

Comment: "`Char temp = NULL;`". Just why would you do that?

Comment: How is `test` declared in the class?

Comment: `void test(char* first,char* buffer);` like so @laune

Comment: You're basically reinventing part of `std::rotate`. Use `std::rotate`.

Comment: I know I am but I prefer to do it myself @chris

Comment: Is the call correct - buffer does point to a Z-string? - Just to make sure ;-)

Comment: What is the point of using members for temporary locations, both temp and back should be local to test?

Answer (score 0):

I think that there is a typo

```
Char* back = NULL;
Char temp = NULL;
```

There should be at least as

```
char* back = NULL;
char temp = NULL;
```

that is keyword `char` is written with lower-case letter c.

As for your function that it is valid. You should check values of buffer and first before calling the function.  For example if first points to the terminating zero then this condition

```
if (first != buffer + strlen(buffer) - 1){
```

will be equal to true and the result will be the same as you got.

Also I do not see any sense to define back and temp outside the function.

Take into account that you could use standard algorithm `std::rotate`

I would write the member function the following way

```
void test( char* buffer ) const
{
   if ( *buffer && *++buffer )
   {
      char c = *buffer;
      *buffer = *( buffer - 1 );
      *( buffer - 1 ) = c;

      test( buffer );
   }
}
```

It is more effective and simpler because it has only one parameter and does not call `std::strlen` each time.